# Is there a quick way to get a users country code?

Tags: php, geolocation

I want to know if the user is browsing from the UK, or using a UK browser. If not, I can safely assume that they are a US visitor.

I can lookup their IP in a database, but this is a bit slow and I'd rather just find out from their User-agent or some other HTTP header.

It doesn't matter if it's not always correct, and there are ambiguities (such as someone using a US computer in the UK).

Comment: Didn't know that there are only two countries in the world. Thanks for keeping us informed.

Comment: Yep, knew that was coming. I said I can safely make this assumption for the purpose of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably check for [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header field.

> 14.4 Accept-Language
>
> The Accept-Language request-header
>   field is similar to Accept, but
>   restricts the set of natural languages
>   that are preferred as a response to
>   the request. Language tags are defined
>   in section 3.10.
>
> ```
>    Accept-Language = "Accept-Language" ":"
>                      1#( language-range [ ";" "q" "=" qvalue ]
> ```
>
> )
>          language-range  = ( ( 1*8ALPHA *( "-" 1*8ALPHA ) ) | "*" )
>
> Each language-range MAY be given an
>   associated quality value which
>   represents an estimate of the user's
>   preference for the languages specified
>   by that range. The quality value
>   defaults to "q=1". For example,
>
> ```
>    Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7
> ```
>
> would mean: "I prefer Danish, but will
>   accept British English and other types
>   of English." A language-range matches
>   a language-tag if it exactly equals
>   the tag, or if it exactly equals a
>   prefix of the tag such that the first
>   tag character following the prefix is
>   "-". The special range "*", if present
>   in the Accept-Language field, matches
>   every tag not matched by any other
>   range present in the Accept-Language
>   field.
>
> ```
>   Note: This use of a prefix matching rule does not imply that
>   language tags are assigned to languages in such a way that it is
>   always true that if a user understands a language with a certain
>   tag, then this user will also understand all languages with tags
>   for which this tag is a prefix. The prefix rule simply allows the
>   use of prefix tags if this is the case.
> ```
>
> The language quality factor assigned
>   to a language-tag by the
>   Accept-Language field is the quality
>   value of the longest language- range
>   in the field that matches the
>   language-tag. If no language- range in
>   the field matches the tag, the
>   language quality factor assigned is 0.
>   If no Accept-Language header is
>   present in the request, the server
>
> SHOULD assume that all languages are
>   equally acceptable. If an
>   Accept-Language header is present,
>   then all languages which are assigned
>   a quality factor greater than 0 are
>   acceptable.
>
> It might be contrary to the privacy
>   expectations of the user to send an
>   Accept-Language header with the
>   complete linguistic preferences of the
>   user in every request. For a
>   discussion of this issue, see section
>   15.1.4.
>
> As intelligibility is highly dependent
>   on the individual user, it is
>   recommended that client applications
>   make the choice of linguistic
>   preference available to the user. If
>   the choice is not made available, then
>   the Accept-Language header field MUST
>   NOT be given in the request.
>
> ```
>   Note: When making the choice of linguistic preference available to
>   the user, we remind implementors of  the fact that users are not
>   familiar with the details of language matching as described above,
>   and should provide appropriate guidance. As an example, users
>   might assume that on selecting "en-gb", they will be served any
>   kind of English document if British English is not available. A
>   user agent might suggest in such a case to add "en" to get the
>   best matching behavior.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> I can lookup their IP in a database, but this is a bit slow

No, it's not.

---

You could use [`Accept-Language` HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) to detect preferred language.